# Whats the difference between char** and char* in this example?

Tags: c, pointers

```
char** surname;
surname = (char**) malloc(size*sizeof(char*));

char* middle_initial;
middle_initial = (char*) malloc(size*sizeof(char));

for(int i = 0; i<5;i++){       
  surname[i] = (char*) malloc(surname_max*sizeof(char));
  middle_initial[i] = *(char*) malloc(middle_max*sizeof(char)); // Please focus on this line
}
```

`surname` is a `double char pointer`, and it makes sense that `surname[i]` is the `i`-th pointer pointed to by `surname`.

However, middle_initial confuses me. Is middle `initial[i]` the `i`-th character pointer? If so, why does `malloc` returns value call for a dereferenced `*(char *)`  instead of `(char *)` during debugging?

** Follow up question**
 I would like middle_initial [i] to be 6 char pointers each having the capacity to point to 1 character. What can I modify above to do such that?

Comment: At a minimum, it's a memory leak.

Comment: `middle_initial[i]` is the i-th character and is not a pointer. But not sure what that line of code is trying to do. It's assigning a random character value to `middle_initial[i]` since `malloc` does not intialise the allocated memory. And it doesn't keep track of the allocated memory pointer so it can't be freed later.

Comment: For the line of code, my intent is to have a character pointer to 1 column of characters. So, middle_initial[i] is a char pointer to one character, middle_initial[i+1] is char pointer to another character

Comment: [No need/Don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714). And `sizeof(char)` is always 1, no need to use it either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dereferencing effectively "reduces the type's pointer count by one".

Every piece of code there is okay, except for...

```
middle_initial[i] = *(char*) malloc(middle_max*sizeof(char));
```

What does this line is supposed to do apart from undefined behaviour? *We don't now*! As the type of `middle_initial` is `char*`, the dereference by index effectively references a `char` object. Then, we have the illogical expression. A `char*` of `middle_max` chars is allocated on the heap, but... that `*` at the front dereferences that allocated memory (memory that can be unitialized, BTW...). Then, such a garbage value is assigned to the forementioned `char` in `middle_initial`. The result of this loop is a `middle_initial` containing garbage chars comming from unrecoverably leaked memory.

And, of course, if `size < 5`, UB everywhere whenever dereferencing!

Comment: Thanks. I have a second question. I would like middle_initial [i] to be 6 char pointers  each having the capacity to point to 1 character. What can I modify above to do such that?

Comment: @JackW: Did you meant *I would like `middle_initial` to be 6 `char*` each having the capacity to point to 1 character*, or *I would like `middle_initial[i]` to be 6 `char*` each having the capacity to point to 1 character*? Depending on the answer, use respectively this for `middle_initial`: `char *middle_initial[6]`. Or this for `middle_initial[i]`: `char *(*middle_initial)[6]`. Say us if you have more questions :).